# How to wait in bash for a result?

Tags: bash

I would like to write a script that first calls `supervisorctl reload` then it runs and runs again `supervisorctl status` until it returns a zero exit code.

What is the proper way of doing that?

Comment: write a loop checking the status code?

Comment: That would be the idea; however, bash often does weird things...
does a script with `set -euxo pipefail` fail, if I do `if [ supervisorctl status ]; then break; fi` or something?

Comment: `it does not return a non-zero exit code.` so until it returns zero? Double-negation is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# first calls supervisorctl reload
supervisorctl reload
# runs again supervisorctl status until it does not return a non-zero exit code.
while ! supervisorctl status; do
   :
done
```

Comment: There's also the lesser known `until` statement: `until supervisorctl status; do sleep 1; done`. You would probably want a sleep command in the loop to avoid churning the CPU while waiting.